# Facebook Graph API posts not appearing for users of page, only admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I created a page on facebook, and am using the graph api to make posts on the timeline.  These post show up just fine for me as the admin, but for users the page is empty.

I verified with the graph api explorer.  As an admin a GET of /NewsCrier/feed is filled with data.

As a non admin user the same request returns

```
{
  "data": [  ]
}
```

Here is an example post from the response of my admin user, notice the privacy is set to public:

```
{
  "id": "383422711781035_404880726301900", 
  "from": {
    "category": "Community", 
    "name": "News Crier", 
    "id": "383422711781035"
  }, 
  "message": "This appears to be the DC shooter, Aaron Alexis", 
  "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQD4wR0Y9UVbb4Js&w=154&h=154&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.justmugshots.com%2Fimg%2F814064%2Flg%2Faaron-alexis.jpg", 
  "link": "http://www.justmugshots.com/texas/fort-worth/814064", 
  "name": "Aaron Alexis, Arrested on 2010-09-04", 
  "caption": "www.justmugshots.com", 
  "description": "Aaron Alexis was arrested in Fort Worth, Texas on 2010-09-04. See the mugshot now.", 
  "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/383422711781035/posts/404880726301900"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/383422711781035/posts/404880726301900"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Public", 
    "value": "EVERYONE", 
    "friends": "", 
    "networks": "", 
    "allow": "", 
    "deny": ""
  }, 
  "type": "link", 
  "status_type": "shared_story", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Reddit News Alerts", 
    "id": "693375074022011"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2013-09-16T19:36:07+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2013-09-16T19:36:07+0000"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your Facebook app is in sandbox mode, as soon as you take the app from sandbox all the users will se the newly created posts ;)