# Facebook posts added via API only showing for app admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created an app so I can auto publish content from a website to it's Facebook page.

The content is being added to the page fine, but only the app admin is able to see it.

```
$message = array(
    'message' => $message,
    'source' => "@.." . $image,
);

$result = $fb->api('/192373517468541/photos','POST',$message);
```

I have a feeling it's some how related to the app status & review, do I need to submit the app for review if it's not a public app? Only the website will have access to its use.

Answer (score 0):

Either I'm stupid or the Facebook app settings has a poor UI.

Under Status you can make the app public (i.e. not sandbox mode), you need a valid email too.

It looked like the app needed to be submitted for review before enabling this, but it's not the case.

Found from answer on this post [Facebook Graph API posts not appearing for users of page, only admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837090/facebook-graph-api-posts-not-appearing-for-users-of-page-only-admin)